# What is the most efficient way to code this part of a T-SQL statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql, coldfusion

I am using SQL Server 2008 and ColdFusion 9.1.2.

I have a query that has an integer field. I need to drop in an integer or a null, not a zero.

Right now, this is what I have:

```
<cfif LOCAL.MyValue eq "">
    NULL ,
<cfelse>
    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#LOCAL.MyValue#">,
</cfif>
```

What is the best way, or most efficient way, or most concise way to code this:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All in one line:

```
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#LOCAL.MyValue#" null="#NOT len(LOCAL.MyValue)#">
```

If it has length, it will set null=false.
If it hasn't got length, it will set null=true, and ignore what's in the `value` attribute.

You may also want to add a trim() inside the len() too (e.g. if a user might possibly enter a space).

Comment: I haven't seen this before, but this is EXACTLY what I was looking for.  So, the NULL part just tests a condition?

Comment: You could also do `null="#val(LOCAL.MyValue) EQ 0#"` which might be more readable and seems to fit your condition a bit better.